# ThreadSample described in android doc. cancelAll() throws exception

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have downloaded the sample ThreadSample 
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html
and add a button which calls `PhotoManager.cancellAll()` which throws the exception

```
 java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.example.android.threadsample.PhotoDownloadRunnable cannot be stored in an array of type com.example.android.threadsample.PhotoTask[]
```

I want to know how it could be fixed and how I could cancel all threads of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which this method tries to do.

Comment: Canceling all threads like this is really not a good idea.  You don't know what the app is doing at that time and what the consequences may be-  for example if the thread is doing file IO reading a config file that must be read to run, the app will break.  Any threads that are canceled must be written very carefully to allow cancellation, and all the code that starts them must be written carefully to accept that those threads may fail to do what they asked them to do.